# Get Comment Text via REST API

Tags: javascript, comments, rest-api

**Added** Note that this process is in a WP plugin, using thw WP API, so I believe this is appropriate for this SO and should not be closed.

The following REST call is used to get a specific comment:

```
var comment_id = 239;   
response = wp.apiRequest( {   // ajax post to set up comment redact meta value
                path: 'wp/v2/comments/' + comment_id  ,
                method: 'POST',
                data: thedata
            } );
```

This returns a JSON object, and the next step is to get the comment text from the JSON object, which contains these values (not complete response, and sanitized):

```
{
  "id": 239,
  "post": 424,
  "parent": 0,
  "author": 1,
  "author_name": "username",
  "author_url": "",
  "date": "2023-02-20T12:43:02",
  "date_gmt": "2023-02-20T20:43:02",
  "content": {
    "rendered": "<div class=\"comment_text\"><p>here is a comment</p>\n</div>"
  },
  "link": "https://example.com/my-test-post/#comment-239",
  "status": "approved",
  "type": "comment",
}
```

My problem is I can't figure out how to get the 'rendered' value. I have tried this:

```
response_array = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
```

but get an error:

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

Still learning JSON, and have done many searches to now avail.

What JS code will get me the comment text out of the response object?

Comment: Thanks. The question is WP-based, I believe, as it is using the WP REST API to get data. Think it is valid for this SO, and should not be closed.

Comment: You mean, "this WPSE"? And to be honest, I was actually going to retract my close vote, but I forgot and when I remembered it back, this question was already closed. But the thing that's specific to WordPress in your post, is *the use of `wp.apiRequest()`* - and you didn't know what it returns (one could guess or do `console.log( response )`, but it's better when explicitly explained).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A brief introduction and what does `wp.apiRequest()` return**

[`wp.apiRequest()`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1.1/src/js/_enqueues/wp/api-request.js) is one of the three JavaScript API written by WordPress <sub>(the other two JavaScript APIs are the [Backbone JavaScript Client](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/backbone-javascript-client/) and [`wp.apiFetch()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-api-fetch/))</sub>, which we can use to communicate with the WordPress REST API, and as for `wp.apiRequest()`, it uses `jQuery.ajax()` which returns a [jqXHR object](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) that implements the Promise interface, giving it all the properties, methods such as `.then()`, and behavior of a Promise. See https://api.jquery.com/Types/#Promise

**The issue with your code**

Originally, I thought *the AJAX request had not been resolved (or not yet complete)* and thus `response.responseText` was an `undefined`, instead of a JSON-encoded string.

Demonstration of the issue:

```js
const response = wp.apiRequest( { ... } );
// Note: That `response` is a jqXHR object.

// At this point, responseText is still an undefined.
console.log( 'before calling .then()', response.responseText, response );

response.then( ( comment, status, jqXHR ) => {
    // At this point, responseText is filled and it's a proper JSON-encoded string.
    console.log( comment, jqXHR.responseText, response.responseText );
} );

// At this point, responseText is also still an undefined.
console.log( 'after calling .then()', response.responseText, response );
```

But then after reading your answer or checking your code there, if you actually did something like this:

```js
.then( function( response ) {
    // Parse the JSON response into a JavaScript object.
    response_array = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
} )
```

Then that `response.responseText` was also (likely) an undefined, because the REST API would not add such property by default, and you should have actually read it from the third parameter, i.e. the `jqXHR` object above.

*But you don't have to manually parse the response text into an object, because the first parameter is already an object representation of the response text.*

**How to properly get the comment text (the value of `content.rendered`) and other data**

You can use `.then()` or these jQuery-specific methods: `.done()` (and `.always()`).

There's already an example above, which uses `.then()`, but here's another example:

```js
wp.apiRequest(
    {
        path: 'wp/v2/comments/' + comment_id,
        method: 'POST',
        data: thedata
    }
).then(
    function ( comment ) {
        console.log( comment.content.rendered );
    }
);
```

If you want `wp.apiRequest()` to return the comment object instead of `jqXHR`, then you can use [`await` and `async`](https://javascript.info/async-await). Here's an example which uses [IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```js
async function editComment( comment_id, thedata ) {
    const comment = await wp.apiRequest(
        {
            path: 'wp/v2/comments/' + comment_id,
            method: 'POST',
            data: thedata
        }
    );

    const commentText = comment?.content?.rendered;
    console.log( commentText ); // This is logged first.

    return comment;
}

// This is an IIFE.
( async () => {
    const comment = await editComment( 123, { content: 'new content here' } );
    console.log( 'after', comment ); // This is logged after the one above.
} )();
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer was correct (and marked as correct), but see my additional answer on how I figured it out before I saw your answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for marking my answer as correct, but I decided to revise it, and hopefully the revision helped you more.

Answer (score 0):

I will mark @SallyCJ's request as correct, but I figured out the answer prior to reading hers (which is similar to what I used successfully), and wanted to supplement her answer with the code that I used to fix the issue.

Note that the answer was provided with ChatGPT, and I verified it worked properly. Here's the relevant code, similar to what SallyCJ posted:

```
    response = wp.apiRequest( {
    path: 'wp/v2/comments/' + comment_id,
    method: 'POST',
    data: thedata,
    fields: 'content',
} ).then( function( response ) {
    // Parse the JSON response into a JavaScript object
    //console.log(response);
  const contentRendered = response.content.rendered;
console.log(contentRendered);

} ).catch( function( error ) {
    console.error( error );
} );
```

My issue was trying to use JSON.parse() on the response, to parse the response into a JS JSON object. But it already was the correct type of object to use. Trying to parse it resulted in the error 'unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data'.

Note that I had done hours of searching here and other places to get an answer, and the ChatGPT gave me the correct answer. I am aware that ChatGPT answers may not be valid or accepted here, but I tested it's answer and it worked properly.

Comment: I have no comments regarding ChatGPT, however as for this - "*it already was the correct type of object to use*" - remember that the response as in `response = wp.apiRequest` vs the one in `.then( function( response )` are not the same type of object. As stated in my answer, that first `response` is a jqXHR object, whereas the other `response` is a *plain object* and it's also available or filled (after the AJAX request is complete) in a property named `responseJSON` of the jqXHR object.